# convert string of hex to string of little endian in c#

Tags: c#, hex, endianness

I have a string representation of an hex number and I want to get a string representation of the little endian.

for example the input is: "112C4F"

the output should be: "4F2C11"

I'm using c# for it.

eventually I came up with this:

```
string text = "3A221C"; 
int tmp = int.Parse(text, NumberStyles.HexNumber); 
var reversedBytes = System.Net.IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(tmp); 
var hex = reversedBytes.ToString("x"); 
var trimmed = hex.Substring(0, text.Length); 
Console.WriteLine(trimmed);
```

the output was "1c223a"

since I don't really know what the third line is doing I'm not sure it will always work as I expect it to work. also I don't know why I had extra zeros that I had to trim?

Comment: What's your current code looking like? What isn't working for you? We do expect you to show your efforts - we are not a coding service.

Comment: I have tried a lot of casting and converting from string, int and arrays. eventually I came up with this:

  string text = "3A221C";
  int tmp = int.Parse(text, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
  var reversedBytes = System.Net.IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(tmp);
  var hex = reversedBytes.ToString("x");
  var trimmed = hex.Substring(0, text.Length);
  Console.WriteLine(trimmed);

the output is: "1c223a"

since I don't really know what the third line is doing I'm not sure it will always work as I expect it to work. also I don't know why I hade extra zeros that I had to trim?

Comment: Please _edit_ the question and add the code to it. As you can see, comments are not a good place for code.

Comment: You have forgotten to explain what is not working for you and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
static string LittleEndian(string num)
{
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(num, 16);
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
    string retval = "";
    foreach (byte b in bytes)
        retval += b.ToString("X2");
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: What if num is int64 not in32?